# How to get names of workbook sheet without parsing the whole file in Node JS

Tags: node.js

I need the names of the workbook sheet without parsing the whole excel. My file contains 1 Million records so parsing the same each time take up lot of time. I am using the following code for now.

```
var xlsx = require('node-xlsx');
var obj = xlsx.parse('file location '+Filename);
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

This code first parses the whole file then provides the sheet name.

Answer (score 0):

Following code is working fine.

```
  const xPopWrapper = require("xlsx-populate-wrapper")
    const path = require("path")
    const filePath = path.resolve(filePathWithName)
    const workbook = new xPopWrapper(filePath)
    workbook.init().then(wb => {
    console.log(wb.getSheetNames())
```